# Removing a DOM element using CasperJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

Okay basically I have a post:

```
<div class=post>
  <div class=content></div>
  <div class=content-meta></div>
</div>
```

thats the prototype of it to help explain

so what I want to do is use some JS to basically delete or hide the div 'content-meta'

Using JQuery I have:

```
$('.content-meta').remove();
```

however when I am using CasperJS I am a little puzzled as how I should implement this code.

I am looking to manipulate a post prior to screen capturing it (the screencapture part works fine)

Heres the code (URL's OMITTED) I have been testing with, It picks up the class just fine, but I have no idea where/how to execute the Jquery to remove the detected element prior to screen capture:

```
casper.start('http://pageurl.com/XYZ', function() {

if (this.exists('.content-meta')) {
    this.echo('found .content-meta', 'INFO');
} else {
    this.echo('.content-meta not found', 'ERROR');
}
this.captureSelector('resultingcapture.png', '.post');
});

casper.run();
```

TL;DR How do you execute JS/Jquery from within a CasperJS function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For execute javascript code from CasperJS, You have to use [evaluate()](http://casperjs.org/api.html#casper.evaluate) method

> The evaluate() method as a gate between the CasperJS environment and the one of the page you have opened; everytime you pass a closure to evaluate(), you're entering the page and execute code as if you were using the browser console.

Your code should be something like this:

```js
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://pageurl.com/XYZ', function() {

   if (this.exists('.content-meta')) {

       this.echo('found .content-meta', 'INFO');

       //evaluates an expression in the current page DOM context.
       this.evaluate(function(){
          //delete div 'content-meta'
          $('.content-meta').remove();
       });

       this.then(function(){
           this.captureSelector('resultingcapture.png', '.post');
       });

  } else {
      this.echo('.content-meta not found', 'ERROR');
  }
});

casper.run();
```

**Note:** This code is going to run only if the webcontext includes jQuery, otherwise you have to remove the div using just javascript.